# Authenticating a user in static_dir single-page-app so that it can call sibling GAE APIs

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, webapp2

I have a React app that is being served on GAE via a static directory.

app.yaml:

```
- url: /my_admin_app
  static_dir: admin_app
  login: required
  secure: always
```

When accessing via browser, GAE presents a login page as expected before continuing to the React app.

Because the React app is completely separate from the GAE app that is also running, I need the web app to call APIs that should require auth, as they control sensitive data.

The React app is calling sensitive APIs behind this URL:

app.yaml:

```
- url: /admin/.*
  login: required // this causes a login page to be sent instead of data
  script: main.app
  secure: always
```

**Is there a better way to serve my static files such that login isn't required again?** Or is there a way to pass along the auth info when GAE presents its own login page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've learned that when Google presents the login, it passes along the auth cookie to the following web page.

Then, any requests that the page makes using `fetch` should specify that the cookie should be passed along with that request.

From the Mozilla docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

> By default, `fetch` won't send or receive any cookies from the server, resulting in unauthenticated requests if the site relies on maintaining a user session (to send cookies, the `credentials` init option must be set).

So to make sure the auth gets passed on:

```
// to only pass to to same origin endpoints
fetch('/endpoint', {credentials:'same-origin'}).then(/*..*/)

// to pass without restriction
fetch('/endpoint', {credentials:'include'}).then(/*..*/)
```